# Finding the properties as an object in an html web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html web page containing the following tags:

```
<div class="user_list">
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483071,'Jack','m');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img " src="..."> </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483075,'Sara','f');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img " src="..."> </div>
    </div>
            ....
</div>
```

I want to make an array of objects containing dropUser parameters in onClick event as shown bellow:

```
array = [
    {id: 2483071, name: 'Jack' , gender: 'm'},
    {id: 2483075, name: 'Sara' , gender: 'f'}, 
    ...
]
```

how may i get that.In my way I want to find the onClick props then map each item to the array objects. I can get the elements by the following method but I dont know how to get the onClick prop then the dropUser parameters.:

```
s.push($(".user_list" ).find( ".user_item" ));

for(let i = 0; i<s.length-1; i++){
  console.log($(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `.attr('onclick')` contain the value for that attribute for each matching element?

Comment: Oh thanks. actually this works:  `console.log($(s[i]).attr('onclick'));`. I used props instead before your comment but not worked.

Comment: Yes I meant that.

Comment: jquery version using .map rather than manually pushing to an array: https://jsfiddle.net/7f0rn3wc/  (essentially the same as existing answers just using map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can achieve it easily:

a) Get the `onclick` attribute value.

b) get data between the `()` and then split it with `,` to make it array.

c) create an object and assign corresponding values to different indexes. Make sure quotes get removed befor assignment.

d) push this object to array created initially.

```js
var arr=[];
$('.user_item').each(function(){
    var onClickDataArr = $(this).attr('onclick').match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(',');
    userData = {
      id: parseInt(onClickDataArr[0]),
      name: onClickDataArr[1].replace(/'/g, ""),
      gender: onClickDataArr[2].replace(/'/g, "")
    };
    arr.push(userData);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user_list">
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483071,'Jack','m');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="..."> </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483075,'Sara','f');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img " src="..."> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery to do this. It's just some simple string parsing to extract this data.

```js
const userItems = document.querySelectorAll('.user_list .user_item');
const dropUsersData = [];

for(userEl of userItems){
  //get the string content of the `onclick` attribute
  const onClickStr = userEl.getAttribute('onclick');
  //remove the function name, wrapping parens, and ending semicolon
  const onClickContent = onClickStr.replace('dropUser(','').replace(');','');
  //Take the params and use the commas to separate each one into an array item
  //Then remove the quote marks around any string literals
  const onClickParams = onClickContent.split(',').map(s=>s.replace(/'/g,''));
  
  //Add the found parameters to the array
  // turning the ID into a real number and
  // saving the actual element reference (if needed)
  dropUsersData.push({
    element: userEl,
    id: parseInt(onClickParams[0], 10),
    name: onClickParams[1],
    gender: onClickParams[2]
  })
}

console.log(dropUsersData);
```

```html
<div class="user_list">
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483071,'Jack','m');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="..."> </div>
    </div>
    <div onclick="dropUser(2483075,'Sara','f');" class="user_item">
        <div class="avatar"><img src="..."> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```